# ActiveRecord undefined method OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This works without the .or() but breaks when I add it:

```
<% @expired = Report.where('EXPIRED < ?', Date.new(2014,12,31)).or(Report.where(EXPIRED: nil)).where(:MAJOR => 1).where.not(:TRIBE => 1).where(:PERMIT_TYPE => 'GENERAL') %>
```

And gives me this error:

```
undefined method `or' for #<Report::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x953e020>
```

Also, doing this gives me a syntax error:

```
Report.where('EXPIRED < ?', Date.new(2014,12,31) OR (EXPIRED: nil))
```

How can I make this OR work?

Rails 4.2.1

Comment: Was `.or()` active in Rails 3? Where did you get the method from?

Comment: @HunterStevens may be the `or` will be shipped with Rails 5. It is currently available in the master branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Report.where("EXPIRED is null or EXPIRED < ?", Date.new(2014,12,31))
```

and for bigger query do this

```
Report.where("EXPIRED is null or EXPIRED < ?", Date.new(2014,12,31)).where(MAJOR: 1, PERMIT_TYPE: "GENERAL" ).where.not(TRIBE: 1)
```